# why negative margin-bottom make the columns equal height?

Tags: html, css

The following css can make all the three  columns equal height,i want to know why?

```
<html>
<style>
body,p{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
    #wrap{
        overflow:hidden;
        width:1200px;
        margin:0 auto;
    }
    #left,#center,#right {
        margin-bottom:-200px;
    }
    #left {
        float:left;
        width:300px;
        background:#777;
    }
    #center {
        float:left;
        width:300px;
        background:red;
    }
    #right {
        float:left;
        width:300px;
        background:green;
    }
    p {color:#FFF;text-align:center}
</style>
<body>
 <div id="wrap">
        <div id="left">
            <p style="height:250px">style="height:250px"</p>
        </div>
        <div id="center">
            <p style="height:300px">style="height:300px"</p>
        </div>
        <div id="right">
            <p style="height:400px">style="height:400px"</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

All the columns are 200px height.
[image]

Why the displayed effect is not this one?

[image]

Because that 200=400-200 ,100=300-200,50=250-200??

What does the `margin-bottom:-200px;` mean here?
Please draw a photo to explain the principle in detail.

Comment: the effect of a negative margin-bottom would shift up the following static element. What you want to obtain can be done with a negative margin-top

Comment: why the three colmuns height not 200=400-200 ,100=300-200,50=250-200? negative margin-bottom would shift up the following static element,does shift up mean minus here?

Comment: Because you assign an overflow hidden on the #wrap div and you put the negative margins on the height of the div tags not on the p tags.

Comment: pls do mark the correct answer.

Comment: Why TO shift up the following static element will result in the effect？

Answer (score 0):

Because you assign an overflow hidden on the #wrap div and you put the negative margins in the height of the div tags not on the p tags.
Here is the example on codepen.
codepen.io/elelowwaydi/pen/grYgYa?editors=1100.

Answer (score 0):

Well it is because of the "wrap" class in the css.
I made a jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/yt0raenm/).
the only thing i did change was deleting the overflow element.
the HTML(unchanged):

```
 <body>
 <div id="wrap">
        <div id="left">
            <p style="height:250px">style="height:250px"</p>
        </div>
        <div id="center">
            <p style="height:300px">style="height:300px"</p>
        </div>
        <div id="right">
            <p style="height:400px">style="height:400px"</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

the CSS:

```
body,p{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#wrap{

    width:1200px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#left,#center,#right {
    margin-bottom:-200px;
}
#left {
    float:left;
    width:300px;
    background:#777;
}
#center {
    float:left;
    width:300px;
    background:red;
}
#right {
    float:left;
    width:300px;
    background:green;
}
#right2 {
    float:left;
    width:300px;
    background:blue;
}
p {color:#FFF;text-align:center}
```